# I'm trying to add a user to a role when reacting to an embed and won't add them

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made a command when using an embed the bot reacts to it and when anyone else reacts to it, it will add them to a rule. But it isn't adding the user to the role and I'm unsure why.

```
    const {MessageEmbed} = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "reactionrole",
  async execute(message, args, client) {
    const channel = '914676864004554803';
    const memberRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Members");

    const emojireact = '';

    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#e42643")
      .setTitle("MineCraft Server Rules")
      .setDescription(
        "To keep our server safe we need a few basic rules for everyone to follow!"
      )
      .setFooter("Please press  to verify and unlock the rest of the server!")

    let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    messageEmbed.react(emojireact);
    
    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async(reaction, user, GUILD_MESSAGES_REACTIONS) => {
      if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
      if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
      if(user.bot) return;
      if(!reaction.message.guild) return;

      if(reaction.message.channel.id === channel) {
        if(reaction.emoji.name === emojireact) {
          await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(memberRole);
        }
      }else {
        return;
      }
    });

  }
}
```

The command shows the embed and the bot reacts but the user isn't added.

Comment: Did you enable the correct intents?

Comment: @Jim yes i did enable everything needed I had problems with intents before and fixed those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how are you not getting a `ReferenceError` but you are passing an unknown variable to the parameter.
At `.add(Members)`, I don't see `Members` defined anywhere in the code you sent.

Comment: I fixed that and defined it to memberrole